# About NavigationFragment

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment

NavgationHostFragment is not working.

```
//activity_main
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment3"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_main"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="131dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="201dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
//nav_main
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_main"
    app:startDestination="@id/welcomeFragment2">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/welcomeFragment2"
        android:name="com.example.fragmenttest.WelcomeFragment"
        android:label="WelcomeFragment" />
</navigation>
```

I don't know why.

The process is not described in the Fragment or other documents.

Please give me a hint how to make the Fragment xml show up instead of Activity_main.
I have been struggling with this for several days.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: from code perspective, everything seems to be alright. add more details about the error you struggling with for several days

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I didn't add theAdapter and it's not showing up.